# Bundling jquery-rails fails with error?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I am trying to include jquery-rails in my Gemfile however I receive the following error:

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
An error occured while installing jquery-rails (1.0.19), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install jquery-rails -v '1.0.19'` succeeds before bundling.
```

`gem install jquery-rails -v '1.0.19'` produces an error as well.
Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Comment: What message did `gem install jquery-rails -v '1.0.19'` produce when it failed?

Comment: Also, which versions of Ruby and Rails are you running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've taken a look at the bug reports for jquery-rails and found [this error](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/pull/35) that's similar to yours. You should try a few of their solutions:

If you are on Linux or OSX run:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
bundle install
```

If that works then you need to modify your profile so those values are set every time you run bundler. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: yes! it worked! how do I set this values for default in my profile?

Comment: Add the export lines to '~/.profile' restart the shell and it should be run every time the shell is started. Test it out and let me know.

Comment: I added   export LANG="en_US.UTF-8" export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"   to the profile but it does not work automatically, i need to write this code every time before starting a new app.